# How to insert strings in BST

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I know how to insert integers into binary search tree

- Smaller to the left
- Larger to the right

[image: Integer]

But that formula would be applicable only if Data/Key is integer.

> So i want to know how do i insert strings into BST

[image: string]

**I have searched the google but couldn't find any answer**

Comment: Maybe you could make use of: String compare to find out if the string is "large" or "less" of the node, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just implement some comparer to which you pass 2 objects no metter of their types(here string) which will tell you which is less or greater. For example it could be a function returning 0 if objects are equal, 1 if first is greater and -1 if first is less. Then instead of comparing like this if(a > c) compare like if(CheckObjects(a, b) = 1)

Comment: Keys in a binary tree do not need to be integers; text books only use that because it’s the simplest data structure that has a total order. But you can use anything else that has an order, e.g. strings using [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit: http://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/ascii2.htm

Analyze the decimal equivalent of the alphabets.

For example: if you want to compare "leopard" and "cobra".
Take first characters of both which are 'l' and 'c', convert them into their decimal equivalent which should be 108 and 99 respectively. Compare them 
if 1st is greater than 2nd then 2nd is smaller and if 2nd is greater than 1st. 1st is smaller. If both are equal, iterate to the next letter of both for example: to compare "fox" and "frog", we cannot find the smaller word by comparing only first character, we need to iterate to the 2nd character which is 'o' and 'r' respectively. Since 'o' is smaller than 'r'. So, "fox" is smaller than "frog".
So compare cobra with leopard only till length 5 (length of word with less total number of characters). if both words are equal till length of word with less total number of characters then the word with greater length will be automatically greater. For example: "character" and "characteristic". Both are equal till length 9 but length of 2nd word is greater. So, 2nd will be greater.

Now, you can see "cobra" is smaller than "leopard". You can also assign values for alphabets by yourself. e.g.

a=1

b=2

c=3

d=4

.

.

.

z=26